# How to remove the word "ïmmediate" when using \maketitle

Tags: titles, authblk

When I use the latex syntax `\maketitle` to write the title, I get a word "immediate" written below it. I googled for an alternative and found something called `\titlepage`. Now when I use `titlepage`, it allocates an entire page for the title. And I don't want that. I just want the word "Immediate" to not appear. How can I do that? Any alternatives you know of?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{authblk}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\title{this is the title}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Comment: How should we remove a word from a code we can't see? Please post the compilable document and give us a clue about the class. I suspect it's some strange typo and it should read `\immediate` in the `\maketitle` code, but that would be even stranger

Comment: @ChristianHupfer i have updated the code

Comment: `\usepackage{kitchen-sink}`. Seriously: Your code is *NOT* minimal.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

After removing packages and code, which do not make `immediate` disappear, the following remains:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{authblk}
\begin{document}
\title{this is the title}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

With the following warning:

```
LaTeX Warning: No \author given.
```

Also, let us make `authorblk`/`\maketitle` happy:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{authblk}
\begin{document}
\title{this is the title}
\author{}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

`immediate` and the warning are now gone.

Nevertheless, the word `immediate` should not appear, if `\author` is not given. It's part of the code, which prints the warning message. A bug report can be made for `authblk` (but I do not know, whether it is maintained, the last version is from 2001). However, why is a package for author affiliations is loaded, if there aren't any authors?

Comment: I had actually placed the author tag after make title, now i have understood the source of error... thanks a lot

Comment: @Rishika Note that `\title`, `\author`, `\date` etc should go *in the preamble*, before even the `\begin{document}`.

Comment: @Bakuriu ok, I did not know that... Thanks a lot